# Specifying up directory in build.xml for ant in windows

Tags: ant, directory, build.xml

I have a build.xml file for ant, and I want to modify a directory from

```
<condition property="flex_sdk" value="%cd%/SDK/flex_sdk/">
        <os family="windows" />
</condition>
```

to

```
<condition property="flex_sdk" value="../SDK/flex_sdk/">
        <os family="windows" />
</condition>
```

The flex_sdk bin directory has .bat files so they are run using cmd /c. I get the error "'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command".

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you show the part of the build that runs the .bat files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try this :

```
<property name="bat.dir" location="${flex_sdk}"/>
```

The location attribute if specified in a property resolves relative paths based on the ${basedir} which is the directory of your ant build.xml file.